# Commerce - Email users on new product input

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, products

Good Afternoon,

Is it possible to have Craft email a list of users (based on a category) when a new product is added to the shop?

Is there a pluigin that would do this, or is it a matter of a small script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this plugin https://plugins.craftcms.com/craft-commerce-back-in-stock

Although I haven't used it, it sounds like it will do what you need.

Always worth having a look for things at https://plugins.craftcms.com

Comment: Thanks for the response, ive actually already reached out to that dev as I thought it maybe able to be adjusted for new products rather than returning stock :)